# Google organic visits totals differences

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have a site that's giving different totals for organic visits from different parts of the Google Analytics tool.

I've used a single day as a date range back in January 2013 to compare and filtered visits data by medium = organic. I get a different total to when I break the visits down by keyword.

Even when I look at Traffic Sources > Sources > Search > Overview and compare to Traffic Sources > Sources > Search > Organic I get different totals.

Has somebody experienced this before and if so any insight as to why this might be?  If not, any suggestions?

Sorry for the delay I've attached some screenshots as suggested:

[image: Organic Visits Overview]

[image: Organic Visits Broken down by Keyword]

I've recently found another site that this happens to with more monthly organic visits.

Comment: May you provide some screenshots to make your question more clear?